# Porting WCF from self-hosting to IIS/AppFabric hosting

Tags: wcf, self-hosting, svc

I have a WCF that has a TCP, HTTP and Mex binding in a self-hosted file, and everything works great. However, and I want to migrate it over to AppFabric, and keep the same bindings, but I'm having a very hard time doing it. I added the WCF Service Application, corrected the svc file, drop the Self-Hosting console application, but I keep getting the awfull `Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]`. error. What changes should I promote from my app.config to my web.config file in order to get this working? I haven't even tried to publish it on IIS, yet... this error that I'm getting is from VS's web server
Below is my previous app.config file for the self-hosting:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="SimpleBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="DefaultTCPBinding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
                sendTimeout="01:00:00" transactionFlow="true" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
            <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="RSAlarmEvent" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
              receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
              transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
              allowCookies="false">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Message">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                  algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="ScriptBindig" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="WebScriptBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
                  httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" maxConcurrentSessions="400"
                  maxConcurrentInstances="464" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="MyServer.Implementation.MyAppImplementation">
          <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultTCPBinding"
                name="MyAppTCPEndpoint" contract="MyServer.Interfaces.IMyApp" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                name="MyAppMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <endpoint address="ws" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding" name="MyApp" contract="MyServer.Interfaces.IMyApp" />
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://desk01:9878/MyAppService" />
              <add baseAddress="http://desk01:9876/MyAppService/" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
      <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What do I need to change? 
Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS alone is not able to host non HTTP endpoints. You must also install (activate feature) Windows Activation Service (WAS). Once installed you must enable net.tcp binding for your site in IIS management console.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have AppFabric installed, with WAS, and the whole nine yards. But this error that I'm getting is still while debugging using Visual Studio's server. I'm not it IIS yet.

Comment: You must be in IIS if you want ot use Net.Tcp. VS integrated web server (Cassini) supports only HTTP endpoints.

Comment: Didn't know that... :-/ Tks for your time and answer! I removed the tcp stuff, and it worked... I'll try it in AppFabric to see how it goes.